# How do I completely overwrite previously edited data such that only the latest one is displayed in Codeigniter?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, echo, edit

I have checked all other related posts but 'could not find any that answers my specific question.

Here's what I have:

```
<input name="job_id" type="hidden" value="<?= $this->uri->segment(3, 0); ?>" />
<?php foreach ($my_preference as $row) : 

if ( $row['status'] == "Open" ) {

    $bgcolor = "#ADD8E6";
}
else if ( $row['status'] == "Approved" ) {

    $bgcolor = "#8CBEE8";
}
else  {

    $bgcolor = "#EDC2B6";

}
?>

        <span style="font-size: 11pt" class="label label-info"> Proposal</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <strong><?= $row['proposal'] ; ?></strong><br/><br/>
        <span style="font-size: 10pt" class="label label-info"> Job Status</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <strong><?= $row['status'] ; ?></strong><br/><br/>
        <center><a href="<?=site_url()?>/provider/edit_proposal/<?= $row['job_id'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">Edit Proposal</a></center>
```

Currently, this allows me to edit my proposal data. The problem I have is, all the previous data is shown in the page, although whenever I click the "Edit" button, what will be displayed on the textbox is the latest data. My question is, how do I completely overwrite all the previously written (and already edited) data? I want to show only the latest data on the page. 
I am looking forward to getting any possible help.

Thanks so much and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

make sure your browser is not cached, also type this and see if it shows the data that you want or something else

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($row); ?>
<?php die(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response..I tried it. It showed the very first array.. I should get the most recent one. How should I do it?

Comment: show me your query and the db structure if possible or data from it.

Comment: Here's what I have, @sarmenHB

Comment: public function edit_proposal() {

  $this->validateRole('provider');
  $this->load->model('job_model');
  
  $id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
  $data['my_preference'] = $this->job_model->get_my_job_proposals($id);  
  
  $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);
  $this->load->view('provider/edit_proposal', $data);
 
 }

Comment: no i meant your mysql query, all that shows is whats being called via a model. also if you can post it via a pastie or something so that its visible.

Comment: or what you can do is type <?= $this->db->last_query();?> and load that page. you should see the very last mysql query that was ran.

Comment: I tried it on my view page as well as in my sql query, but did not have any effect.. I got same result..

Comment: This is my query, @sarmenHB                                        public function job_proposal_edit_submit() {
  $this->validateRole('provider');
  $this->load->model('job_model');
  
  $this->job_model->add_job_proposal_from_provider($_POST);  
  
  redirect('provider/view_job/' . $_POST['job_id'] . "?message=Proposal submitted.");
  
 }

Comment: msg me on gtalk and ill try to help. sarmenhb@gmail.com