# Issue with adding form in codeigniter given certain condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, submit, addition, conditional-statements

I wanted to allow user to send application to a certain job.  I originally allowed editing but had some issues as in here: [How do I completely overwrite previously edited data such that only the latest one is displayed in Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751131/how-do-i-completely-overwrite-previously-edited-data-such-that-only-the-latest-o) 
After trying different ways to solve it, I still could not. But it almost does not matter now because I realized the original plan I had would produce more issues. Besides, in real life, proposal should be made once, so the best should be submitted.
My issue now is, even if a certain user has already sent an application, every time he tries to visit the same job post, "Apply" button still works, thus multiple application is still made. I tried to change something on my model, but it still did not work.

Here's what I have in my provider controller:

```
public function write_proposal() 
{
    //allows provider to send proposal to client
    $this->validateRole('provider');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
    $data['my_preference'] = $this->job_model->get_my_job_proposals($id);   
    //$data['id'] = $id;        

    $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);
    $this->load->view('provider/write_proposal', $data);

}

public function job_proposal_submit() 
{
    //completes proposal submission
    $this->validateRole('provider');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $this->job_model->add_job_proposal_from_provider($_POST);       

    redirect('provider/view_job/' . $_POST['job_id'] . "?message=Proposal submitted.");

}
```

And this corresponding one in my job model..

```
    public function add_job_proposal_from_provider($obj) 
{
    //I wanted to make here the condition that adding new proposal will only work if the user has not yet submitted any proposal for the specific job but it produced another error, and that is none of the at least two proposals made is shown or probably even saved
    //if ($obj['proposal'] == NULL){

    $data = array
    (
        'proposal' => $obj['proposal'],
        'job_id' => $obj['job_id'],
        'status' => "Open",
        'provider_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
    );

    $this->db->insert('job_proposal', $data);
    //}
}
```

I look forward to any help. Thanks

Comment: what error you are facing have you load model ?

Comment: Although the message "Job proposal submitted" is shown, reality is, the second or third and so on job proposal created would no longer be shown.. Not even the first one.

Comment: can you show your full code

Comment: I added code in my controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things,

First, consider implementing a view-side limitation, while it won't stop someone clever it will improve your UI alot(users won't have buttons that work but won't do anything).

I'm assuming users have to login to send applications, else this whole thing wouldn't be too useful.

What I would do is create a table with all the job IDs, every time a user applies to a job, you add him to that table.

When a user tries to apply for a job, you first check if there's a match for that jobID/userID in this table, If there's no match, You can move along and check if the information was posted correctly and actually add the information to the database, and also to that jobID/userID table(so he can't post twice).

On the view side, I would send a variable to the view with all the jobID's this current user has applied to and use simple ifs or javascript to disable the buttons(or show alerts when the user tries to push the buttons).

I hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thanks for this @patrick. Just like you, I am really better in concepts, but not so much in actual implementation.. I've been trying my best though..

Comment: I think I'm missing something on your actual question if this didn't answer the concepts of what you need to do. 

What is your desired outcome?

Comment: ultimately, desired outcome is to not allow logged in provider to send more than one application..

Comment: In that case, My answer fits perfectly.
You must create the jobID/userID (both foreign keys) and check when the user clicks "submit" if that pair exists.

If provider(id=32) is applying to jobID(id=40) you run a query on that table, if that pair 40/32 exists, (sql table returns 1 row), you do not process the order. if it doesn't exist you insert it to the database. 

you can even run a callback on the submit button to check if the provider applied to that job already or not. 

If you have problems in specific code, Tell me where and I'll try to help

Comment: thanks for your help patrick. I'm a student with a very limited time now to fix my program issue. I am actually supposed to have submitted my paper including reaction of some other students on my app. my deadline for all these stuff is just until tomorrow. When I started developing my project, every time I would encounter a certain issue, I normally spent so much time fixing it by myself.If I only knew I could get help from here months back, I could have finished my project a lot earlier.. thanks for your explanation and your time.. I probably will just go back to this after another impt issue

Comment: I thought this should be more important in my project.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879049/issues-dealing-with-tables-and-joined-linked-contents-codeigniter

Comment: Well I won't answer in that other question you posted, as it's the same question as this one.

I already gave you the answer aswell, You must implement a table that has jobid/userid and run a select on it to see if the user already submitted a job, There's  no other way I could think of that would make sense.

Comment: I already posted some code Patrick.. kindly check what's wrong.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887187/how-do-i-get-certain-columns-from-two-different-tables-using-status-as-condition